# Cannot get d3 force graph to have xlink:href (clickable) nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've tried to add `xlink:href` dummy URL just to see if I'm getting anywhere, but I am completely stuck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Job graph</title>
  <style>
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #666;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    #licensing {
      fill: green;
    }
    
    .link.licensing {
      stroke: green;
    }
    
    .link.resolved {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
    }
    
    circle {
      stroke: #333;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      pointer-events: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var links = [{
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1
    }];
    var nodes = [{
      "id": "p1"
    }, {
      "id",
      "p2"
    }];
    var node_fills = {
      "p1": "rgba(204,204,204,0.5)",
      "p2": "rgba(204,204,204,0.5)"
    };

    var width = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .size([width, height])
      .linkDistance(60)
      .charge(-300)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("marker")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
      .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
      });

    var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return "http://google.com/" + d.id
      })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return node_fills[d.id];
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", ".31em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
      path.attr("d", linkArc);
      circle.attr("transform", transform);
      text.attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A `<text>` element must not have a `xlink:href` attribute: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextElement.

Comment: @altocumulus Indeed, I was getting desparate. Originally I wanted the circle to be clickable and take me to the URL.. I have edited the code in order to move it back to the circle.

Comment: The same holds true for `<circle>` elements. It's all in the same spec. Like the [`<a>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#Links) element you are probably after.

Comment: I got it working thanks to your help! In circle element, I insert an append of an `a` element, followed by the `xlink:href` `attr`. Thanks!

Comment: If that works, good for you. Unfortunately, this is not correct usage of the `<a>`: it should be around the circle, not inside. The spec does not allow elements other than animation or descriptive elements as content of a `<circle>`.

Comment: Alternatively, just add an event listener to those circles.